# return _default_decoder.decode(s) error after reading json file in python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
url = 'https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Delhi-NCR'
result = requests.get(url)
data = result.json()
```

I'm trying to execute the above code but getting the following error.
Is there any other module or library that i need to import or is it some syntax error? I've tried importing it by BeautifulSoup but since it's a dynamically loading page, it won't work.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:910, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    909 try:
--> 910     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    911 except JSONDecodeError as e:
    912     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    913     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    333 """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334 containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336 """
--> 337 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338 end = _w(s, end).end()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 url = 'https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Delhi-NCR'
      2 result = requests.get(url)
----> 3 data = result.json()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:917, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    915     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.message)
    916 else:
--> 917     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
```

Comment: The error message is incomplete.

Comment: For dynamic HTML there is Selenium library which controls a browser to let it do the hard work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the response content is an html. Do `print(result.text)` and you'll see :-D

Check if a different url will give you a json, otherwise, you may need to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org) to parse the html.

Comment: It's a dynamically loading page so BeautifulSop won't work hence trying to import it as json file.

Comment: Yes, the page is created dinamically, and you download a static version of it, which contains the data, so I expect you could parse it and retrieve the data you need. However, @platipus_on_fire (neat name bro) gave you an easier solution.
Also, you can use selenium to scrape dinamic pages, but it's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

That page is pulling its results from an API via an XHR call (check Dev Tools - Network tab). You need to scrape that particular endpoint, to get the json data. Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.magicbricks.com/mbsrp/propertySearch.html?editSearch=Y&category=S&propertyType=10002,10003,10021,10022&city=3327-1001011&page=2&groupstart=30&offset=0&maxOffset=13&sortBy=premiumRecent&pType=10002,10003,10021,10022&isNRI=Y'

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
```

This returns a (fairly big) JSON response:

```
{'nsrResultList': None, 'resultList': [{'encId': 'VNJDDhBvWUJzpSvf+uAgZw==', 'possStatusD': 'Ready to Move', 'pmtSource': 'android', 'cntvl': '100', 'url': '2-BHK-940-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-K-R-Puram-in-Bangalore&id=4d423630333031323033', 'floorNo': '2', 'noBfCt': 0, 'st': 516, 'modstat': '20205', 'lCtDate': 1660792748000, 'appVer': 350, 'appSub': 'Y', 'deviceType': 'and', 'sendbirdId': '487111c6-5cb4-49e6-a35a-2dfa97bd6b62dipa6275', 'lastAccessDate': 1655404200000, 'projectSocietyLink': 'teja-nivas-k-r-puram-bangalore-pdpid-4d4235313830303531', 'sipro': '52063429 61161925 62018289 59395151', 'comFlag': 'N', 'appExc': 'N', 'cScore': '100', 'postDateT': '2022-08-11T23:54:46.000Z', 'endDateT': '2022-12-09T23:54:46.000Z', 'pl': 'Y', 'luxAmenities': '12223 12216', 'luxAmenitiesD': 'RO Water System,Visitor Parking', 'appovedAuthC': 'ABADev', 'nriPref': 'Y', 'enc_Id': 'VNJDDhBvWUKzvQzSxKfkaA==', 'cowDays': 0, 'price': 4200000, 'priceD': '42 Lac',....}
```

Comment: This is working for this url but isnt working for a different url from the same website. Any idea why that may be happening? '''--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)''' It's throwing this error

Comment: The api endpoinrt above is interrogated when user is looking for properties in Bangalore (I think, I don't remember exactly what location I searched for). If you change the location, the api endpoint will have different attributes. @abhijeetpolkamwar

Comment: is there a way I can work around it? Or should I use selenium or scrapy?

Comment: What is your goal? What re you trying to achieve?

Comment: working on this project where i'm trying to scrape data off of a real estate listing website into a working python dataframe for further analysis and geoplotting and predictions.